# Image "moves" when varying heightForRowAtIndexPath in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I have a table view with varying height, as defined in the heightForRowAtIndexPath. For some very odd reason, the image is "indented" to the right based on the height; if the height is low enough, the image is stuck to the left side of the cell, but as the height increases, the image for said cell is shifted rightward compared to other rows.

The result of this is a very poor looking list, with images floppily laid out in a zig-zag pattern depending on the height of each individual row.

The problem is revealed by this simple example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return (indexPath.row+1) * 50;
}
```

Each cell is set up (simplified) as a "Subtitle" style cell with:

```
// ...
cell.textLabel.text = @"foo";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"bar";
cell.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // for debugging; i have images with transparent bg
cell.imageView.image = anImageThatIs55x50pixelsBig;
return cell;
```

Any ideas? My head bleeds from the wall-love-affair.

Edit: uploaded a screen which displays this. The "image" is just a screenshot of a tiny area of the screen which makes it look a little weird, but you get the picture I'm sure: http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/549/screenshot20100311at172.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you add your own UIImageView to the UITableViewCell instead of using the built in one? I believe the built in one is designed to add padding if there is room for it and ignore it if there is not.

Comment: For testing purposes you can just create the UIImageView and then use the cell's addSubview method, if this ends up being your solution you should probably subclass the UITableViewCell.

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much for that idea! At some point I definitely ought to make my own cell, but for now, the following did the trick (in cellForRowAtIndexPath):

    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]/2-26,55,55)];
    cell.indentationLevel = 5; // to not get text inside the image
    iv.image = theImage;
    [cell addSubview:iv];
    [iv release];

Answer (score 0):

A potential cause could be the `contentMode`.

`UIView` (a superclass of `UIImageView`) defines the property `contentMode`, which determines how a view lays out its content when its bounds rectangle changes. You may want to change this property to another mode, as in the case of an `UIImageView` it determines how and where an image is drawn.

Comment: I've tried changing the contentMode for the cell, the cell's view, and the imageView to various things but it doesn't seem to do anything whatsoever. :/